# Onion skin option disappeared

Tags: animation, 2d, dopesheet, layers, draw-mode

I have run into a problem. I'm new to blender, and i'm working on an animation. The onion skin button was working/showing and then it disappeared from the layers menu. Could anyone help me bring it back? [image: onionskinnotworking]

Comment: I think you've encountered a bug, because even turning it off in Overlays shouldn't make the option disappear from the layers.  I notice you're on 2.90. I know that there have been Grease Pencil bug fixes since, although I don't know if they're related.  Can you try 2.93.5?

Comment: I'll try 2.93.5, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to view menu and turn on "SHow sliders".

[image]

Comment: that fixed it! thank you so much!

Comment: If useful please upvote the reply.